# Using sequential values for the primary key in an INSERT query

Tags: oracle

How can I write an insert query for an Oracle database which has a sequential primary key so that the insert statement automatically takes the next number in the sequence?

```
INSERT INTO LD_USER_ROLE(USER_ROLE_ID,INS_USER,INS_DATE, USERNAME) 
VALUES (100, 'sp22',to_date('2003/05/03 21:02:44','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),'JOHN BARRY', )
```

In the above statement I have hardcoded the value of 100 for the key 'USER_ROLE_ID' but I'd like to alter this as explained in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from using a trigger, you can use a sequence directly in the insert statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE LD_USER_ROLE_SEQ;

INSERT INTO LD_USER_ROLE
   (USER_ROLE_ID,INS_USER,INS_DATE, USERNAME) 
VALUES 
   (ld_user_role_seq.nextval, 'sp22',to_date('2003/05/03 21:02:44','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),'JOHN BARRY', )
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just create a trigger for your sequence like this:

Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE LD_USER_ROLE_SEQ
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE NOMINVALUE NOCYCLE NOCACHE NOORDER;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LD_USER_ROLE_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON LD_USER_ROLE
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT LD_USER_ROLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.USER_ROLE_ID FROM DUAL;
END;
```

The trigger will automatically get the next value/id on every insert (like auto_increment in mysql).

Comment: need a semicolon at the end of your CREATE SEQUENCE, brah.